Are there any philosophers who clearly define the word "consciousness" in their arguments?
My view of consciousness lies somewhere in the illusionist camp, i.e. more or less with the likes of Daniel Dennett. However, while reading through the literature, I am frustrated by the fact that it seems hard to find a clear definition of the "map" they are referring to when they use the word "consciousness". This seems to me to create a lot of confusion in subsequent debates. I am not convinced at all that most uses of the word refer to any actual territory, but when you can not even discern what map people are working with, the discussion becomes even more difficult.
The most basic definition of consciousness would seem to me to be the acceptance of the existence of a "first person" perspective, that this is in fact a possibility that is allowed by the laws of physics. This seems absolutely undeniable, but also in some ways quite uninteresting. If this is the only definition you are working with, it seems logical to argue that the "first person" must be some fundamental property of the universe, in which case it would follow that a rock might also be conscious (albeit experiencing a very uninteresting state of consciousness). You can argue that the map of "information processing" is a special case, but it does not seem obvious at all why information processing should give rise to any exceptional state that is excluded from all other matter. If the laws of physics allow for the existence of the "first person" perspective, why should this be reserved to matter organised in some particular fashion? You also run into trouble with the notion of computers. If information processing is necessary for the "first person" view to exist, well then a calculator is conscious, and so, certainly, are LLMs.
The slightly "higher order" definition that I think most people seem to work with implicitly is one that refers in some way or another to the existence of an "I", a coherent entity of some kind. But you already run into some trouble here when you try to spell out the details of the map that the word "I" is referring to. For instance, is this "I" coherent over time? If so, what would be the physical basis for this coherence? The specific matter of your brain? But that matter is swapped out over time anyways, and I can think of no logical reason to assume that you would even notice if all the atoms of your brain were exchanged instantly with a different set. People do not even notice when their cortex is scooped out during neurosurgery, or notice any subjective difference when the two halves of their brains have been disconnected.
And if not the particular atoms, then what? The specific patterns of neural connections? But this arguments implies that if you make an exact clone from different matter, then you and that clone should share the same first person perspective, at least before your neural patterns start to diverge. This seems like a nonsensical conclusion that puts the map of "consciousness" before the territory of two obviously separate organisms. You can "cheat" this particular thought experiment by assigning a special property to the specific position of matter in physical space, because the thought experiment then becomes impossible to conduct (you cannot have two separate beings in the exact same position). However, I can't think of a good reason to assume that spatial position should confer any special property.
In the end, to me the only logical conclusion seems to be that the concept of a temporally coherent "I" is illogical, that it is a map without a corresponding territory. The only thing you're left with is the "I" of the moment, but this entity is quite easily accounted for by current neuroscientific understanding. It is simply the brain solving the task "identify yourself", accessing the results of previous solutions from memory, or the implicit feeling of being coherent over time. That feeling is quite easily explained as an illusion that has been selected for evolutionarily, for the same reasons that we are served the illusion of perceiving a coherent visual field. It seems beneficial to an organism's self preservation tendencies if it believes itself to exist tomorrow, and the week after, and ten years from now. And even if the evolutionary derived belief in the self has been profoundly embedded into the core of our biological computation medium, this does not make it a map that corresponds to any real territory. I get the impression that the whole reason the discussion on consciousness is so contentious is because most people's definition of the word is in reality just a reference to this particular feeling. Discussing the nature of consciousness using this definition seems no different than discussing the nature of sadness, or any other particular human emotion.
Anyways, my impression is that if you reason your way in this direction, and disassociate the definition of the word "I" from temporal coherence, from memory, from normal cognition and so on, well then you end up with a definition of consciousness which is indistinguishable from the basic "first person perspective". So we end up exactly where we started.
So the basic definition is useless (in the sense that you cannot really use it to conclude anything), and the next step up that I can think of is either illogical or pretty much the same thing as the first. And I can't think of what definitions would lie "between" these two. In fact, it seems to me that the moment you try to define the word, you've pretty much solved the discussion by the time you're done. I have been looking for perspectives that contradict this view, that expose some flaw in this line of thinking, but it seems difficult to know exactly where to look. Unfortunately, from what I've read of "illusionist" (like Daniel Dennett) perspectives so far, they usually dismiss "consciousness" without ever clearly defining exactly the exact map they are dismissing. It usually seems to be some "higher order" definition of the word, but I'm not exactly sure. I haven't read all they have to say about the topic, so I might have missed the exact point where this issue is dealt with, and I would love it if someone could point me to it.
I've also looked for a rebuttal of this argument in the criticism of the illusionist viewpoint, such as by John Searle, but most of what I've read seems to be some variation of confusion from people not defining their words properly, or statements that completely miss the point (of the sort: "You can't dismiss consciousness because I am conscious"). I might misunderstand their arguments though, so if someone could spell it out in a way that cohesively refutes what I've already mentioned, that would also be great.

"If this is the only definition you are working with, it seems logical to argue that the "first person" must be some fundamental property of the universe, in which case it would follow that a rock might also be conscious (albeit exeperiencing a very uninteresting state of consciousness)." - quite so!

A non-opinionated overview of allmost all current theories: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0079610723001128

"If information processing is necessary for the "first person" view to exist, well then a calculator is conscious, and certainly LLMs."  "sufficient" is the word you want there. A is necessary for B if B -> A. A is sufficient for B if A -> B.

"why should this be reserved to matter organised in some particular fashion? You also run into trouble with the notion computers. If information processing is necessary for the "first person" view to exist, well then a calculator is conscious, and certainly LLMs"-- There are very few non-trivial properties that matter holds regardless of its organization, basically only momentum, energy, spin, and occupation of some region of spacetime. So much does depend heavily on its constituent organization: being a fish, being red, being a human, etc. And being necessary doesn't mean sufficient.

Also Dennett was against panpsychism (that everything has some degree of consciousness) for being too vague and inconsequential

"Consciousness" as the word is used in modern philosophy (after David Chalmers) is a very precise notion that is widely understood. But it does not lend itself to a definition in words, because it is not like anything else.

J Kusin — as far as I can tell, Dennett was not just against panpsychism. He was against qualia.

@causative But... but... of course rocks are conscious!

"That which is aware of being aware."

@DanielAsimov oh he definitely was against it. He would trot out “niftyism” in retort- that everything is nifty to some degree.

J Kusin: Nobody knows what you mean, because you never said what you mean by "it".

One of the weaknesses of Western (and in particular empiricist) philosophy is that it can take a bizarrely objectivist perspective. In essence, it demands that things be seen 'from the outside' to eliminate subjective impressions. In most cases this is both feasible and functional — who wants a subjectivist approach to the physics of falling bodies? — but it tends to deny the existence of any internal experience at all, which can be troubling.
I mean honestly… Anyone who wakes up in the morning has an array of experiences — sights, smells, sounds, thoughts, etc. — that are purely and intractably subjective, but that make up our entire life. Does anyone need objective, third-party verification that they smell coffee brewing? One might need third-party verification that actual coffee is brewing somewhere, because there are other ways one might perceive that smell, but the perception of smell itself is indisputable. And it's worth noting that the type of 'objectivity' that empiricists demand is actually intersubjectivity: a state in which the subjective experiences of a number of individuals correlate. One can not do empiricism without subjective experience.
The term 'consciousness' points at this array of subjective experiences. That's not meant as a definition; it's merely an observation. We can break down this array into various levels:

(Mere) awareness: the simple translation of sensory stimuli into subjective experience
Focal attention: the organization of subjective experience in a foreground/background model, so that particular objects of attention can subjectively appear, taking prominence or receding to the background as our attention shifts
Ideation: the further organization of objects of focal attention into categories, causal relationships, conceptual structures, etc

'Consciousness' in philosophical traditions generally means focal attention. Things like stones or amoebas might arguably have mere awareness, but we don't generally ascribe consciousness to them because they don't seem to have the capacity to shift attention. Likewise, few philosophies require ideation to establish consciousness. As a rule ideation is required to establish 'identity', since identity is a type of mental categorization, but consciousness precedes identity. In fact, that's the root of the "temporally coherent 'I'" paradox presented in the question. Focal awareness (consciousness proper) has no true sense of time, except in the transition between objects of focus. That 'timeless' awareness is at the root of the conceptual structures that define the sense of "I", and so the self sees itself as continuous and coherent.
The illusionism perspective has always reminded me of an old joke:

Sitting in his study, Descartes suddenly exclaimed: "That's it! I see
now! I think, therefore I am!" At that moment the butler walked in and
asked if Descartes would like his afternoon tea. Descartes said "Hmm, I
think not", and immediately disappeared.

The illusionism perspective starts with the premise that all of the subjective experiences we have (as a matter of focal attention) are akin to sleight-of-hand: i.e., that we are fooled into thinking we have consciousness because we are focusing in the wrong direction, and if we just saw things the 'right' way we'd realize what a cute, silly trick it all is. But the problem is that whichever way we look — even iff it's in the 'right' direction — we're still looking. Someday we may deeply understand awareness, focal attention, and ideation, but understanding them won't change the nature of them at all. It only comes off that way because illusionism is firmly fixed in that questionable and bizarrely objectivist perspective.

"the perception of smell itself is indisputable" - I would dispute that. People who have brain damage often smell things (like toast or coffee) due to faulty perception; https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/24799-phantosmia

@Valorum: If person X says "I smell coffee" there are only two options: (1) X is lying, and (2) X perceives the smell of coffee. In case 2 the source of that perception might be due to brain damage, hallucination, synesthesia, or actual coffee, but the perception itself is indisputable. X smells coffee. Right now you are seeing this text. If I convinced you the text was a hallucination, that would not change the fact that you are seeing the text; it would just change your understanding of the situation.

Objectively, there are a wide range of things that smell like coffee that aren't coffee. Civet spray, for example has a pungent odour that is sometimes mistaken. Nobody is suggesting your subjective experience is necessarily an hallucination, just that you might be wrong.

@Valorum: I'm not making any claim about being 'objectively' right or wrong. I'm saying one indisputably perceives the smell of coffee. If you were to tell me it's civet spray, I'd say: "Wow, civet spray sure smells like coffee!" Careful here… if you undercut the facticity of perception, you undercut all of empirical science.

I would read David Chalmers and also Heidegger. It sounds like it can help you develop your ideas, partially in conversation with those thinkers. There is also the “integrated information theory of consciousness” or something - an attempt to define consciousness mathematically, but I don’t know too much about if they’ve come up with anything yet.
It sounds sort of like you are interested in both the phenomenology approach and the more logical-mathematical approach, so I think you could study other standard authors in the former like Merleau Ponty and maybe Husserl.
There’s also a theory called the “CTMU” (Cognitive-theoretic Model of the Universe) that I don’t know much about, but it presents itself as a mathematical theory of metaphysics showing the necessary conditions of the relationship between the mind and the physical world.
Lastly, I think some work coming out of Wolfram research right now is showing how in computational models the idea of an “observer” can arise, and I think this is relevant to the question of what a precise notion of “being conscious” is. (See Wolfram Physics and the Ruliad).

Thanks a lot for this overview!
Looking into it, the "integrated information theory of consciousness" seems not to exactly touch on the issue directly, as it assumes consciousness as a given, and works from there. I found Anil Seth's comments on IIT it and panpsychism, interesting, although he doesn't directly refute any of the points. As to the "CTMU", I am wary of long chains of logic that build conclusions on central axioms. To put it shortly, they tend to end up as very irrational. As to the Ruliad, I am at a loss of how this concept exactly would apply to the concept of consciousness.

When considering IIT, you'll want to be aware of Aaronson's counterexamples: https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=1799

What you're conscious of is, first of all, information that is accessible to you. This is not a definition, but it does help to narrow down what we're talking about. If you are conscious of a yellow duck, that means that there is an encoding of the yellow duck in your brain which is accessible to the executive functions of your brain. We may compare it to a computer program that interfaces with a database; the entries in the database are accessible to the computer program, because the program can look them up when the need arises.
This accessibility shows itself empirically in that you can talk about the yellow duck, you can track the yellow duck with your eyes if it moves, you can count how many legs the yellow duck has, and so on. The presence of information about the duck allows your executive function to complete tasks regarding the duck, if the need arises.
Note that accessibility is not the same as actual access. Back to the computer program: the entries in the database are all accessible to the program, but at any point in the program's execution it will be currently accessing very few if any of them.
Similarly, in your brain, you are not necessarily talking about the yellow duck, tracking it with your eyes, or counting its legs. The "executive function" part of your brain has the potential to do all that, but is usually not currently doing it. When you aren't specifically thinking about the duck, information about the duck usually resides only in areas of your brain devoted to visual processing. It's a "row in the database" rather than loaded directly into the "program" (your executive function).
However, it is not the case that you are conscious of all information that is accessible to your executive function. If you have a book containing a picture of a yellow duck, then the executive function part of your brain can potentially access this picture by opening the book, but if it has not done so yet, we do not say you are conscious of the picture. The picture is accessible, but not part of consciousness. Also, if you have a distant memory of a yellow duck that's still a bit hazy - it's not easy to remember, it would take you some time and effort to dredge it forth - then we would not say you are conscious of that memory. Not until you've actually remembered it.
So what you are conscious of is information that has a certain high level of immediate accessibility - something your executive function can potentially access without much delay, effort, or intermediate planning steps.
But what's the threshold for delay or effort?
To answer that, the reason your executive function might access the information is, again, to perform tasks. To achieve objectives. We can say that if a certain piece of information could have helped you to achieve some task, but you failed to act on it, then you weren't conscious of it.
If you are tasked with pointing at the yellow duck, and you cannot find the right direction to point - then you were not conscious of the duck, even if it was in your field of view. Or at least, you were not conscious of the location of the duck.
So just as accessibility of a piece of information by your executive function is a requirement to be conscious of it, failure to access a piece of information when it would have been useful to an objective means you were not conscious of it.
This allows us to describe the threshold for delay or effort that divides conscious from non-conscious information. If your executive function takes any definite action that would have been improved had you accounted for the information, then you weren't conscious of it in that moment. The threshold is therefore the delay between definite actions taken by your executive function. To make it into consciousness, information needs to be accessible in less time than that delay.
This leaves open the question of what counts as a "definite action." We may sidestep this question by taking it as an input to the model. One specifies an agent by describing the set of actions it may take at each time step. Then we can decide which information the agent was conscious of at each time step, based on whether the information was accessible to improve the action taken by the agent, relative to some possible objective (regardless of whether the agent actually had that objective on that time step).


Consciousness is the internal cognitive state which everybody normally
experiences when being awake. That’s called the first person view on
consciousness. A typical but basic example of a conscious experience
is a colour expression: One experiences that an apple looks green,
while other fruits look red.
Subjective experiences like these are named quale (plural:
qualia) by philosophers.

To investigate consciousness from the third person view is what
neuroscience mainly does: To search for the neuronal correlate of
consciousness, i.e. which network of mental processes has to be active in
order that a person has conscious experiences.
A good introduction
by a neuroscientist on an intermediate level is Christof Koch
Consciousness

A main project of neuroscience is to develop a scientific model
which explains how the mental processes in the brain create the
subjective experience.
One of the most ambitious attemps is
“Integrated Information Theory” (IIT), see IIT 4.0.  The paper is challenging, IIT even attemps at a mathematical model.


Aside: Please clarify by a reference which “map” mentioned by Daniel Dennett you mean in the beginning of your post.

Obviously, this is one of the big questions of philosophy. Apart from it being at the center of philosophy since its occidental beginnings (Γνῶθι σαυτόν) it is intricately connected to the question "what is all the other stuff": At the same time, it provides the means to tackle it and already answers part of it.1
Unfortunately, I don't think it has been solved yet, but from this computer guy's perspective I can guarantee you two things:

Research into artificial intelligence will provide fundamental and unexpected insights, even more than it has already. To me, it is clear that mental functions, including consciousness and emotions, are not bound to a specific substrate, like a brain consisting of neurons embedded in a biological body.
Psychology and philosophy are — with all due respect — notoriously inaccurate sciences where statements are hard to falsify or verify. Diametrically opposed stances coexist happily for extended periods of time.3 As every programmer knows, the attempt to actually implement something will make you painfully aware of any problems with the specification as well as any prior misconceptions.

From introspection and basic considerations it seems clear to me that part of the phenomenon of consciousness is connected to the notion of feedback. That idea is already present in the quoted motto on the Temple of Apollo which contains the reflexive pronoun σαυτόν (or σεαυτόν): Know yourself. We are somehow capable of perceiving ourselves without ending up in an infinite feedback loop.2
Given that premise, I would also argue that any attempt to define "the consciousness" as a unique, clearly-definable state of being is a misconception. Clearly, all organisms contain feedback loops: They react to their environments by way of "sensors" (cells or organs which change state depending on environmental and inner conditions) whose state can be "perceived" in the sense that the organism reacts to that. Every organism has some ability to perceive itself. In primitive organisms, these sensors and reactions are primitive; in higher organisms, both are more complex. To me it would be preposterous to suggest that the great apes, dogs or dolphins do not possess some traits that we commonly associate with consciousness.
"Consciousness" is a spectrum; different organisms are on different locations on that scale.4



1 Therefore, even if we are not primarily interested in ourselves but in all the other stuff, for example when we try to define what is true (or at least how we can tell), we need at the same time a concept of self and its interactions with the world.
2 I'd actually suggest that excessive recursion is underlying some forms of mental illness.
3 This is certainly true for definitions of "consciousness".
4 Since "ontogeny recapitulates phylogeny" (which is not quite true but was a nice concept), we can also observe this spectrum in a baby. Would we call a newborn (or a fetus) "conscious"? Probably not; for example, it cannot pass the mirror test, a sign of self-awareness commonly associated with consciousness. It takes a few weeks until a baby starts to react to its environment on a more than entirely instinctive and reflexive level. It seems absurd to assign a specific moment in time where a sudden switch from "not conscious" to "conscious" takes place.
